# case with multiple conditions to produce output even when some conditons are not met

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have written a query that makes use of a multi-conditional CASE statement to perform an analyze of table data, based on an aggregate function, for example:

```
select country,
(case when country in ('DE','FR','IT') then 'Europe'
when country in ('CH','JP','SK') then 'Asia'
when country in ('US','CN') then 'North America'
else 'Other' end) as 'Continent', 
count(*) as NR 
from citizenship
group by country,
(case when country in ('DE','FR','IT') then 'Europe'
when country in ('CH','JP','SK') then 'Asia'
when country in ('US','CN') then 'North America'
else 'Other' end)
```

Things are pretty straight forward until now, but I need that when there are 0 rows in the table to meet one of the case conditions, to have it displayed in the output, like with a NULL or some other predefined value, such as:

```
 | COUNTRY | Continent | NR |
 |   IT    |   Europe  | 5  |
 |         |   Asia    | 0  |
```

and so on...

Is it possible to be achieved, considering that the real query is like 500 rows long, due to many conditions applied in when clauses, and the table has nearly 60M rows? Also in this environment I can not create additional db objects.

Comment: @Stephen it is working, but it does not show all the conditions stated in case when they are not met. So Asia does not appear, and that's what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @Stephen yes, correct, I want them all to appear, even when the CASE has 0 matches for one or more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE continents (NAME VARCHAR(30))
INSERT INTO continents VALUES ('Europe');
INSERT INTO continents VALUES ('Asia');
INSERT INTO continents VALUES ('North America');
INSERT INTO continents VALUES ('Other');
 SELECT * FROM continents

 CREATE TABLE citizenship (country VARCHAR(2));
 INSERT INTO citizenship VALUES ('DE')
  INSERT INTO citizenship VALUES ('IT')
  INSERT INTO citizenship VALUES ('IT')


SELECT A.NAME AS CONTINENT, B.COUNTRY, COALESCE(NR,0) AS NR 
FROM continents A 
LEFT JOIN (
select country
    ,case when country in ('DE','FR','IT') then 'Europe'
    when country in ('CH','JP','SK') then 'Asia'
    when country in ('US','CN') then 'North America'
    else 'Other' end as Continent
    ,COALESCE(count(*),0) as NR 
from citizenship
group by country,
(case when country in ('DE','FR','IT') then 'Europe'
when country in ('CH','JP','SK') then 'Asia'
when country in ('US','CN') then 'North America'
else 'Other' end)
) B ON A.name = B.CONTINENT
```

Output:

```
    CONTINENT                      COUNTRY NR
------------------------------ ------- -----------
Europe                         DE      1
Europe                         IT      2
Asia                           NULL    0
North America                  NULL    0
Other                          NULL    0
```

Comment: Yes, that works since I have tried it before, thank you for the answer, but I have to run this query in a production environment where I am not allowed to add database objects :/

Comment: That's the way to do it! (However, it would be even better with a derived table - to avoid writing the case expression twice.)

Comment: @gm08, do a UNION ALL from dual, one select per continent.

Comment: It is easy to substitute the table continents with a ` SELECT UNION ALL  SELECT...`

Comment: Yes guys, you are absolutely correct. I can use a big UNION ALL  for all my CASE clauses, and the LEFT JOIN will make sure that all these values appear. It took a while to my clogged brain to get it, but now it is all clear. I am going to test it in my real table, let's hope it won't add much to the execution time.

Comment: @etsa If it only was continents for real, it would have been really good :) I have nearly 40 distinct values, and they might increase, but I will manage it somehow